# Error when converting string into xml element

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I tried to give the value to parentElement in my function

here's the function

```
Private Shared Function AddDynamicChildElement(parentElement As XmlElement, url As [String], title As [String], description As [String]) As XmlElement
    ' Create new element from the parameters
    Dim childElement As XmlElement = parentElement.OwnerDocument.CreateElement(SiteMapNodeName)
    childElement.SetAttribute("url", url)
    childElement.SetAttribute("title", title)
    childElement.SetAttribute("description", description)

    ' Add it to the parent
    parentElement.AppendChild(childElement)
    Return childElement
End Function
```

I called AddDynamicChildElement in my Page_Load like this

```
AddDynamicChildElement(root,"Home.aspx","Home","This is Home Page")
```

I need to give the value to my "root" there. I got root's value from user input which is String so I need to convert it to XmlElement

here's my code

```
Private Function header_pointing(strRoot As String) As XmlElement
    Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

    If strRoot = "STANDARD" Then
        doc.LoadXml("General Preference")
    ElseIf strRoot = "PA" Then
        doc.LoadXml("Personal Administration")
    ElseIf strRoot = "TA" Then
        doc.LoadXml("Time Attendance & Leave Administration")
    ElseIf strRoot = "PG" Then
        doc.LoadXml("Personal Government")
    ElseIf strRoot = "PY" Then
        doc.LoadXml("Payroll Administration")
    ElseIf strRoot = "RC" Then
        doc.LoadXml("Recruitment Management")
    ElseIf strRoot = "PF" Then
        doc.LoadXml("Performance Management")
    ElseIf strRoot = "LO" Then
        doc.LoadXml("Load Administration")
    ElseIf strRoot = "MD" Then
        doc.LoadXml("Medical Administration")
    ElseIf strRoot = "RE" Then
        doc.LoadXml("Reimbursement Administration")
    ElseIf strRoot = "LD" Then
        doc.LoadXml("Learning And Development Management")
    ElseIf strRoot = "CT" Then
        doc.LoadXml("Catering Administration")
    ElseIf strRoot = "CR" Then
        doc.LoadXml("Custom Report")
    ElseIf strRoot = "SRR" Then
        doc.LoadXml("Special Request Report")
    ElseIf strRoot = "TOOLS" Then
        doc.LoadXml("Tools")
    Else
        doc.LoadXml(strRoot)
    End If

    Return doc.DocumentElement
End Function
```

When I run this code, it throw an error

here's is the error

```
System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

It point to the last line of my code

is there any suggestion what the cause and how to correct it??

Appreciate all help/suggestion

Comment: Simple, not one single one of the strings that you're trying to load is valid XML syntax.  It's not clear what your trying to achieve, but you need to look at things like `doc.CreateElement("nodename")`

Comment: Ok I will update my question with what actually I wanna do

Comment: @Julian, next time, you may want to start this way... Explaining what you actually want to do!

Comment: I have edited it and sorry for my mistakes

Comment: Where is `header_pointing` called from?

Comment: before I called AddDynamicChildElements

Comment: Sorry @Julian, but exactly how are we supposed to know things like this?  How are we supposed to read your mind and figure out what you're trying to do, when you're not giving us all the information straight off??

Comment: So are you simply trying to change the name of the DocumentElement?

Comment: wanna my full code????I didn't quitely understand this code so sorry

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood your what you're trying to do (which is to change the name of the root element), try this.

It requires you to overwrite the existing `XmlDocument` object with the return object:

```
Private Function header_pointing(doc as XmlDocument, strRoot As String) As XmlDocument
    Dim elName as string = ""
    Select Case strRoot
        Case "STANDARD"
            elName = "GeneralPreference"
        Case "PA"
            elName = "PersonalAdministration"
        ...
        Case Else
            elName = strRoot.Replace(" ","")
    End Select

    Dim newDoc as New XmlDocument()
    Dim newRoot as XmlElement = docNew.CreateElement(elName)
    newDoc.AppendChild(newRoot)
    newRoot.InnerXml = doc.DocumentElement.InnerXml
    Return newDoc
End Function
```